# psych - Getting cumulative Variance from fa loadings

Tags: r, psych, factor-analysis

I am using the psych package's fa command for factor analysis, and so have an object of class fa. I can query the loadings with fac$loadings,but how can I capture the bottom half of the loadings, which gives the SS loadings and the Proportion and cumulative Variance.

Example code:

```
library(psych)
data(bfi)
fac <- fa(r=cor(bfi, use="complete.obs"), nfactors=5, fm="ml", rotate="none")
fac$loadings
```

And how can I extract the follow information?

```
                 ML1   ML2   ML3   ML4   ML5
SS loadings    4.429 2.423 1.562 1.331 0.966
Proportion Var 0.158 0.087 0.056 0.048 0.034
Cumulative Var 0.158 0.245 0.301 0.348 0.383
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running `str(fac)` it seems that you can get the data you're interested in with

```
df <- fac$Vaccounted
> df
                            ML1        ML2       ML3       ML4        ML5
SS loadings           4.4291169 2.42278894 1.5623383 1.3308373 0.96561620
Proportion Var        0.1581827 0.08652818 0.0557978 0.0475299 0.03448629
Cumulative Var        0.1581827 0.24471092 0.3005087 0.3480386 0.38252492
Proportion Explained  0.4135227 0.22620272 0.1458671 0.1242531 0.09015437
Cumulative Proportion 0.4135227 0.63972545 0.7855925 0.9098456 1.00000000
```